# iOS problems after Bundle ID change, Xcode "failed to upload"

Tags: xcode, ios, info.plist

When doing something as simple as changing a Bundle ID, my apps consistently have problems. Sure ideally I will have the proper bundle ID to begin with, but that isn't the reality with this team.

Even after cleaning a project, deleting the app from devices it is installed on, even deleting Xcode's compile folders, and rebuilding the app, why do I get these errors such as "Failed to upload x.app (xcode 3)" , Xcode4 gets really weird when this happens too

Am I supposed to change something else? I am currently only changing the text of the Bundle identifier field of the Info.plist

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is not really a deal breaker. When Xcode 3 says "Failed to upload app.app", the app is most likely already on the device. Always on the device in my experience. It just did not automatically start the app and the debugger is not linked.

You should be able to test for crashes at least.